# XSD - How to allow elements in any order any number of times in XML?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I am trying to create a schema and have come across this problem

I am trying to create an XSD, and trying to write the definition with the following requirement:

- Allow child element specified to appear any number of times (0 to
  unbounded)
- Allow child elements to be in any order

XML:

```
<xml-doc-out>
   <complex sys-name="abcd" isType="sequence" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <property sys-name="A" isType="list" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
      <property sys-name="B" isType="list" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
      <complex sys-name="D" isType="sequence" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
      <complex sys-name="E" isType="sequence" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
      <property sys-name="F" isType="bool" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
    </complex>
 </xml-doc-out>
```

**Current XSD:**

```
        <s:complexType name="COMPLEX_DSC_TYPE">
            <s:sequence>
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="property" type="s0:PROPERTY_DSC_TYPE"/>
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="complex" type="s0:COMPLEX_DSC_TYPE"/>
            </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
```

**ERROR:**  Unecpected subelement. I guess it's giving issue as  element coming after .

What is the correct XSD for the above mention XML?

**XSD I Tried:**

```
   <s:complexType name="COMPLEX_DSC_TYPE">
        <s:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <s:element name="property" type="s0:PROPERTY_DSC_TYPE"/>
            <s:element name="complex" type="s0:COMPLEX_DSC_TYPE"/>
        </s:choice>
     </s:complexType>
```

Comment: Please read and follow the instructions on how to create a [mcve].  What you've posted is a jumbled mess of extraneous elements, attributes, malformed XML, and incomplete XSD fragments.  You shouldn't expect anyone to wade through that and guess what you want.  (My guess is that you can achieve what you want via a simple `<xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">` wrapper around the elements you wish to repeat any number of times in any order, but you've got to clean up your question significantly before it merits receiving good, detailed answers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML isn't well-formed but I'm trying to guess your intent from the indentation. I think what you want is

```
<s:complexType name="COMPLEX_DSC_TYPE">
   <s:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <s:element name="property" type="s0:PROPERTY_DSC_TYPE"/>
      <s:element name="complex" type="s0:COMPLEX_DSC_TYPE"/>
   </s:choice>
</s:complexType>
```

Comment: I already tried this scenario. Getting the following error - "The element ''complex" has invalid child element 'property'. List of possible lements expected 'complex'."

Comment: @SkAzharuddin: Had you posted a [mcve], the answers you'd have received would have easily avoided such additional errors.  It's not too late to correct the mistake and receive a comprehensive answer.  Read and follow the above link carefully.